# How I can convert string into html inside of html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor

I got html tagged string like

```html
<p>I want to trip/remove seconds from date time. 
I checked some solution but showing solution using 
format string like
</p> 
<pre><code class="language-c#"> 
DateTime datetime = DateTime.UtcNow; 
</code></pre>
```

as result of my c*ontrollers action* passed down into *view*. How I can decode it into html formatting inside from html? Or maybe I can someway generate html page in my *action* and append it to existing document?

Comment: Have a look at [Expression encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#expression-encoding). Please pay attention to the **Warning**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw()`:

```
@Html.Raw(htmlString)
```

And I agree with Ali's comment.

> Using HtmlHelper.Raw on unsanitized user input is a security risk. User input might contain malicious JavaScript or other exploits. Sanitizing user input is difficult. Avoid using HtmlHelper.Raw with user input.

Comment: In my case it close to warning case - I need to render new posts on a blog, but posts can be added only by approved user, which slightly decrease danger. But there still is? Is there another way I can build around it?